# One query instead of multiple queries

Tags: php, mysql

I'm currently running multiple mysql queries but want to just run one and loop through it. How can I improve this?

```
 $query = mysql_query("SELECT productid, code, size, quantity, sizechart, rprice, price, weight FROM inventory WHERE code = '$productcode1'"); 
 while ($rows1 = mysql_fetch_array($query)) 
 { 
     $productids1 = $rows1['productid']; 
     $codes1 = $rows1['code']; 
     $sizes1 = ucwords($rows1['size']); 
     $quantitys1 = $rows1['quantity']; 
     $sizechart = $rows1['sizechart']; 
     $rprice = $rows1['rprice']; 
     $sprice = $rows1['price']; 
     $dweight = $rows1['weight']; 
 }
```

Each query then carries on the same but $productcode2 and $productcode3 etc.

Answer (score 6):

... WHERE code IN ('$productcode1','$productcode2',...)

Comment: by using where in, how would l then fetch results for each row that matches each productcode? like in the example above. row1, row2 etc?

Comment: I am not sure I understand. You already have a loop `while ($rows1 = mysql_fetch_array($query))` which would iterate through each row. The query would return rows that matched any of the productcodes in your list when using where..in

Answer (score 1):

Change "Where code = '$prouctcode1'" on "where code IN (...)"

Answer (score 1):

One solution would be using [PDO's prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php).

Quick, untested and dirty example based on PHP reference:

```
$stmt = $dbh->prepare("SELECT productid, code, size, quantity, sizechart, rprice, price, weight FROM inventory WHERE code = :code");
$stmt->bindParam(':code', $code);

foreach ($productCodes as $code) {
  $stmt->execute();
  $rows = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
  // Do something with the results
}
```

Comment: Argh, totally misunderstood the question. Well, try this if you actually want to run multiple queries in a more efficient way.